# Animation class that can update other objects' values

Tags: java, animation

I want a Animations class that can be reused through different projects. The problem is how I let the class change another object's members (such as position). Here is a very simplified version of how it would operate and what it can do.

```
public class Animation() {

    private float currValue, targetValue, duration;

    public Animation(currValue, targetValue, duration) {
        this.currValue = currValue; 
        this.targetValue = targetValue;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void update() {
        // Here I would update its currValue based on duration and target
    }
}
```

So when I want to animate let's say a rectangle's position I would do:

```
class Rectangle {

    private float x, y;
    private Animation a;

    public Rectangle (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.a = new Animation(x, 100, 1000); // Duration in ms
    }

    public void update() {
        a.update(); // Update animation
    }
}
```

Obviously this does not work, because Animation does not update Rectangle's x value. Only one solution comes to mind, and that is passing in the instance of Rectangle and the field name "x" and then use the Reflection API to update the value. But that seems like a pretty poor solution.

Any suggestions? Should I design my code differently?

Comment: By "reusable" I assume you mean reusable in Swing projects? You could take a look at the examples at http://filthyrichclients.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is not necessarily a poor solution in this case. In fact, it's a very general solution that allows elegant code on the client side. But of course, one should be aware of the caveats of using reflection in general.

A very pragmatic approach of such an animation would be to "factor out" what the animation actually does: Namely changing some `float` value, in your case. So one way of separating the "client" code and the implementation could be the following:

```
interface FloatSetter {
    void setFloat(float f);
}

public class Animation 
{
    private float currValue, targetValue, duration;
    private FloatSetter floatSetter;

    public Animation(
        float currValue, float targetValue, float duration,
        FloatSetter floatSetter) 
    {
        this.currValue = currValue; 
        this.targetValue = targetValue;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.floatSetter = floatSetter;
    }

    public void update() 
    {
        ...
        floatSetter.setFloat(currValue);
    }
}
```

Then you can pass an appropriate implementation of `FloatSetter` to your `Animation` - probably via an anonymous inner class:

```
class Rectangle 
{
    private float x, y;
    private Animation a;

    public Rectangle(float fx, float fy) {
        this.x = fx;
        this.y = fy;
        FloatSetter floatSetter = new FloatSetter()
        {
            @Override
            public void setFloat(float f)
            {
                this.x = f;
            }
        });
        this.a = new Animation(x, 100, 1000, floatSetter);
    }

    public void update() {
        a.update(); // Update animation
    }
}
```

BTW: Depending on what you are going to achieve, I'd recommend to **not** put the `Animation` instance into the `Rectangle`. But I assume that this is just a sketch to show your intention.

**Important** : You should definitiely have a look at the "Timing Framework": https://java.net/projects/timingframework . It is the accompanying code for chapters of the book "Filthy Rich Clients" (  http://filthyrichclients.org/ ) by Chet Haase and Romain Guy, and they certainly know their stuff. The library is a *very* sophisticated and flexible implementation of what you obviously want to achieve there. (They also support a generic "PropertySetter" that uses reflection (https://java.net/projects/timingframework/sources/svn/content/trunk/timingframework-core/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/core/animation/timing/PropertySetter.java?rev=423 ), but this is just one helper class to define a general "TimingTarget", which is the sophisticated version of the "FloatSetter" that I sketched above).